# Typescript force generic type to be an object

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a generic function with generic types that must be of a particular object type, **not just any object**. Specifically, I am trying to create a wrapper around the AWS Lambda handler function with well defined types for the request and response headers bodies.

Here is the best solution I have been able to find so far:

```
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult, Context } from 'aws-lambda';

export type AsyncHandler = (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent, context: Context) => Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult>;

interface EmptyInterface {
    _?: string;
}

export type RequestQueryParameters = EmptyInterface;
export type RequestHeaders = EmptyInterface;
export type RequestBody = EmptyInterface;

export interface Request<Q extends RequestQueryParameters, H extends RequestHeaders, B extends RequestBody> {
    queryParameters: Q;
    headers: H;
    body?: B;
}

export type ResponseHeaders = EmptyInterface;
export type ResponseBody = EmptyInterface;

export interface Response<H extends ResponseHeaders, B extends ResponseBody> {
    statusCode: number;
    headers?: H;
    body: B;
}

export function createHandler<Q, H, B, RH, RB>(main: (request: Request<Q, H, B>) => Promise<Response<RH, RB>>): AsyncHandler {
    return async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
        const response = await main({
            queryParameters: (event.queryStringParameters as unknown) as Q,
            headers: (event.headers as unknown) as H,
            body: event.body ? (JSON.parse(event.body) as B) : undefined,
        });
        return {
            statusCode: response.statusCode,
            headers: response.headers as Record<string, string> | undefined,
            body: JSON.stringify(response.body),
        };
    };
}
```

And here would be an example usage:

```
interface TestRequestQueryParameters extends RequestQueryParameters {
    a: string;
}

interface TestRequestHeaders extends RequestHeaders {
    b: string;
}

interface TestRequestBody extends RequestBody {
    c: string;
    d?: string;
    e: number;
}

interface TestResponseHeaders extends ResponseHeaders {
    f: string;
}

interface TestResponseBody extends ResponseBody {
    g: string;
    h?: string;
    i: number;
}

const main = async (
    request: Request<TestRequestQueryParameters, TestRequestHeaders, TestRequestBody>,
): Promise<Response<TestResponseHeaders, TestResponseBody>> => {
    console.log(request.queryParameters.a);
    console.log(request.headers.b);
    console.log(request.body.c);
    console.log(request.body.d);
    console.log(request.body.e);
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            f: 'test',
        },
        body: {
            g: 'test',
            h: 'test',
            i: 100,
        },
    };
};

export const handler = createHandler(main);
```

The problems with this approach are:

1. I can't enforce that the query parameters and headers are strings.
2. All of the methods have a dangling `_` prop.

**Any suggestions on how to improve this? Is there an existing library for wrapping AWS Lambda handlers?**

---

Edit: With the help of @jcalz, I have improved the code by using `Q extends Record<keyof Q, string | undefined>`. But there are still two things I would like to improve:

1. The type definition for `createHandler` has become very verbose. Is there a way to simplify it?
2. I can't have optional fields (e.g. `b?: string`) in the input/output interfaces. I can get around this by doing `b: string | undefined`. But is there a way I can do `b?: string`?

Here is the updated example code: https://tsplay.dev/WkvlDm

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mA7g4w), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  (So no unexpected errors with `--strict` compiler flags, and some code that highlights the problems with your approach.) This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: Also, could you explain what the point of `EmptyInterface` really is? If you are trying to enforce "a particular object type, not just any object" in TypeScript, you will have to represent that particular type structurally, as there is no [nominal typing to speak of](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible).  If you can't distinguish a desired object from an undesirable one structurally, then maybe there really isn't a difference.  How would you tell at runtime, for example, whether you've got the "right" type?

Comment: Have you looked at [@types/aws-lambda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/aws-lambda) package?

Comment: @jcalz, here is a [fixed typescript playground example](https://shorturl.at/qtM03). To clarify, I can define the structure that I want. I want the main function passed to `createHandler` to have a response headers object that has string keys and string values. But hypothetical `main1` and `main2` functions should each be able to have a different set of keys.

Comment: The purpose of `EmptyInterface` is to force each type (e.g. `ResponseHeaders`) to be an object instead of a string, number, etc.

Comment: Ideally, I would do something along the lines of `interface TestResposneHeaders extends Record<string, string | undefined> { ... }` but then I am able to return additional headers beyond just the ones explicitly defined in the `TestResponseHeaders` implementation.

Comment: That url just brings me to the https://www.shorturl.at/ main page and not any playground example; could you check it?  You should also edit the question itself to contain any externally linked info as plain text.  If you want an object, you can use [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type)... you might be also able to do something generic like `Q extends Record<keyof Q: string | undefined>`, but without a [mcve] I can't really be sure.

Comment: Sorry for the bad link. `Q extends Record<keyof Q, string | undefined>` is what I was looking for. But there are still a few things I would like to improve on it. If you can help with those and post it all as an answer, I will accept it! See my edits to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For types where you want to allow anything whatsoever as long as it is an object and not a [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive), you can use [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type).  This should be the case for your `B`-like type parameters, whose values you have (in your tsplay link at the bottom) only constrained to `any | undefined` (which is just `any`, by the way).

For types where you want to make sure that the values are constrained to `string` or `undefined`, and you want to support optional properties, I'd create a type alias like this:

```
type OptStrDict<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: string }
```

You will use it to [recursively constrain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) your type parameters like `T extends OptStrDict<T>`.

---

So your `Request` interface becomes, for example:

```
export interface Request<
    Q extends OptStrDict<Q>,
    H extends OptStrDict<H>,
    B extends object
    > {
    queryParameters: Q;
    headers: H;
    body?: B;
}
```

I will dispense with writing out the full version of your code with these changes, but you can verify that this works via the Playground link below.

---

Note that re-use of the `OptStrDict` type alias will reduce verbosity of your code, especially if you shorten it to `OSD` or something.  If you think that `createHandler()`'s type signature is still too wordy after this, I'm not sure how best to proceed; pragmatically speaking, having five constrained generic type parameters is going to take up some space no matter what you do.  ‍♂️

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQQAoEkDiBDGBTAd2wE9UoIAPYgUQDc8A7GAGhQx3yNPKoCU8AzgFcANizgBhCEzwV4AXzgAzciDgBybAQEBaEdhAAjACbZ1AbgBQl2ZFhwYxMHhQDiDAMYAJbA2Mi8KDgAXjgACjx6JgAuNixcQhIyShoo8Q9pfDlYqRk5AEoQgD44ZJBgATwAHjR4ziSeYn5hMSKrS0dnOAB5MBgAZRgoABFgDxgqgBUS0KQAbQBpOGAGOABrPGIIJThJgF0AfliBIZWAczh5a1toeBX8KCVsDxd+AEchQQnLOF+4AEU4LJ8H4BD0+oMRmMJv8iswfn8vEC5IxjGDegMhqNxlUvHCEb8AELIkFouAQQwAKzw4wJcBKCDpH0CpGwUAMeAeAli-ysfzgAAs8NhjIFuXAvHy-oYIMZiEc4ISrFcbBQ7HcZI9nq9BJAGJVcSTUeiIVjobi4YqjaDyVSaTAGXSTrghAIpKLYgwhEZAlLfkKRWKFZK6TK5bElZYVTd7EohJ4YMBpHAPFBhfgfH4AlAqnT3oDgcbwZioTj85b3kjCzaMZDsRNKxW8G9idWyRTqeN4fzmlWUTXTaWG4I8axmq3++27bSimEQNgVrEwmnmSdYu9Picqvmx82vLuW0VCsESmUKtVmnqDb3dwJCUUj7FkG5PJn-IFEHS0zAhFBVtgXw8cJIkYGAn3YBIuGSKg6FA1gMjyMDJEyYF8liM8DVqDhEm4FJmlEB1ik-fl+QQk44DTAQrxcUItAXeB5xWMJGRI1i4GZKBWXZEBOTFJcQKYAA6DjiEhc5UDZDkuTgAC4HjNYGAgAgGEKWSdzpNjBWFUUoHFCI0kEgMdLBWT5MU5TVLBStu006VZWIWIBJgQSw2IOADnCAApfpugAOUEsA2UqfTQJc+zLLgd5CUKWJ41FJQVjwYwbNY+R8j9Ejv1-VYWNs35nR-N1ZTwWJKOowSCtdd08BS2yjL4ijdWkSpDO0sUZKsmloGMKoTigc5WD684SgAHzkvw8AShgktqzTXNiby-Iq04GDOYAlGIZcmv1PAwrlfJZr+eQMuOqNrHuQInheXYvg3L5-k+TiJO43jdOIv5sGOFazmVc7NSulxJlu5tNxgLw2re3LfkMBUhtWuAxriybEuMX7LAurVrqBk47pOQl7Pe34PC+-rVoy4wSfODKSrgL0fSgNGMYBm6ce2ypwcDSG6SUSmybO9H-u1FmYEvZq8HxuVCbgM5eZ+ukBVljLgE9b1DF9fmyIYhdVlowDwi-EGvnXQ2t2xkWTZgB6WWeqSxVYM3cbBiGBHt4HVxgCXiHxNDSlUc9tzZ6oHcDjnjNd1mqLFz2HyIqGU2aiAAkEkQIDOLb3eEx6uNt3TBOwdK6TIxPdpTtOV1B1rOYEFyC-5LK-yl-lKqKj04AAJgABg7w7-Wd2I480nmNHwE51B7y5x-mxu2Jl4evjHjS2IVufR-H-llbgABGLvx-kWrTtO1V1Xj-V4AFXx3yCUJU3TPA32zOdtfSoA)